# How to read properties in SQL file to replace placeholders/Environment variables?

Tags: sql, ant, environment-variables, flyway

I have a flyway SQL script which inserts some data which is environment specific (Like deployment URL's) etc. I am having these values in a properties file. I want to use the same properties in this SQL file. I can do this by ant replace task/sed from bash file.In that case i need to run the script/ant target manually. Is there any other way to read properties in SQL file to read as ENVIRONMENT variable/replace placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this using flyway. We can use flyway placeholders.

```
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway"
      init-method="migrate" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="disableInitCheck" value="true"></property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>migration-sql</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholders">
        <map>
            <entry key="key1" value="${value1}"></entry>
            <entry key="key2" value="${value2}"></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

properties file:

```
value1= value of key 1

value2= value of key 2
```

Reference:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418173/how-do-placeholders-work-in-flyway), 
[Flyway Feature request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1088)