# Retrieve properties in flyway java migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have a springboot application with flyway migrations, and I want to write a java migration which uses an external parameter. As I have understood spring is completely out of the question since the migration is done by just flyway, but is there any other way of providing properties that the java class can use during migration? The parameters are to be used by the application later on but I do not mind duplicating the data as long as it can be externally configured (properties file, environment variable etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do placeholders work in Flyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418173/how-do-placeholders-work-in-flyway)

Comment: @V.Mokrecov Almost :D It seems that the placeholder can only be used directly in the insert sql? I want to use the placeholder in a java variable so that I can perform some logic on it, and then insert that calculated value into the database.

Comment: My be this - https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/java

Comment: @V.Mokrecov Found the issue, when using placeholders it is mandatory to extend BaseSpringJdbcMigration instead of implementing SpringJdbcMigration, as the former exposes the FlywayConfiguration to the migration.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep in mind.