# How to secure sensitive information in flyway sql files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I use Flyway with Spring boot to version control my DB, all well and good.

The issue is the SQL files will be stored in my source code under `resources/db/migration/..`, and it's hosted on Github, so if someone could get my source code somehow from there, he will get all my database.

And also, in my case, I use a lot of TOKENS to connect with different external apps, and I found nothing in the Flyway docs that says how to hide sensible information in your SQL files.

so my questions are:

1. How to secure the SQL files so that they will not be stored inside source code ?
2. If there is no way to hide those SQL files, so how to secure sensitive information inside SQL files ?

Comment: See if this helps. Using flyway placeholders https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585624/17981941

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Flyway itself does not contain a method to secure files.
You could mount a secured drive at runtime and point Flyway at that location for the SQL files. You can change the location Flyway uses to look for SQL files using the [`locations`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/placeholder) parameter.

Also, as mentioned by @dhanraj in a comment, Flyway does have the concept of [Placeholders](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/placeholder) to inject data into scripts. So, for examples, a TOKEN could be set up as a environment variable on a secure environment and injected that way.